# How done function works in passport js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have `auth` function, I want it to authenticate my user route.

```
// auth.js

function auth(request, response, next) {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, async (error, token) => {
        if (error || !token) {
            response.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
        } 
        next(token);
    })(request, response, next);
    next()
}

module.exports = auth;
```

And heres my jwt strategy

```
// passport.js

passport.use(
  new JwtStrategy(opts, (payload, done) => {
    console.log('payload', payload)  // this works
    User.findById(payload.id)
      .then(user => {
        if (user) {
          console.log('here user', user) // this also works
          return done(null, user);
        }

        return done(null, false);
      })
  })
);
```

But why when I console log my request It doesn't show me the user that I already declare in `done(null, user)`

```
const auth = require('../auth.js')

router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.user) // return undefined
   // other code
});
```

Comment: what do you get when you console.log(req) instead of req.user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple issues that I can see:

- From your `auth()` middleware function, your are calling `next()` before passport has had a chance to authenticate the incoming request - which happens asynchronously. You should remove the synchronous call to `next()` there, and defer to `passport.authenticate()` callback to handle this.
- In `passport.authenticate()` callback, you're calling `next()` with an argument - express will take this as an error occurring and jump to the next error middleware in line.

Edit: I also checked the signature of the `passport.authenticate()` callback and it seems to be `(error, user, info)` - not `(error, token)`.

Edit 2: It also seems like when passing `passport.authenticate()` a custom callback, it becomes your responsability to expose `user` on the `req` object by calling passport `req.login()` function. Please take a look here:

- http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/ (custom callback section at the end)
- http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/